# Cannot load multiple commenting system in Jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to implement disqus and facebook commenting system for different categories in jekyll blog.

Here is my current approach.

```
     
  {% for category in site.categories %}

  {% if category.type == "personal" %}

  {% include facebook.html %}

  {% else %}

  {% include disqus.html %}

  {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

`Expected result:` Facebook comment should be loaded in category `personal` from facebook.html otherwise disqus comment should be loaded in all other category.

`Actual result:` Disqus comments loads automatically in personal category regardless of the loop.

What should be changed  to make the comments load correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to print disqus or facebook on each page depending on "personnal" category presence.

As @marcanuy says, you have to refer to `page.categories`, which is an array.

```
{% if page.categories contains "personnal" %}
  {% include facebook.html %}
{% else %}
  {% include disqus.html %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Category doesn't have a `type` attribute. Checking directly like:

```
  {% for category in page.categories %}

  {% if category == "personal" %}

  {% include facebook.html %}

  {% else %}

  {% include disqus.html %}

  {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Should detect the personal category and load *disqus* comments.

Comment: the issue still persist., however inside of _if loop_, disqus gets loaded over and over again. Is there any other way to filter using liquid syntax?

Comment: how are you defining categories?

Comment: Use `page.categories` instead of `site.categories`, then loop the way mentioned above.

Comment: using "contains" on checking liquid syntax for presence of string or substring rather than comparing them. `{% if page.category contains "personal" %} ` does the trick rather than  ==

Comment: @cdrrazan my original answer meant to replace your `if` clause inside the `for` loop, that is the way it works following your original code. Anyway, using contains and avoiding the `for` loop is a more elegant soliution.